# How redirect dynamic subdomain to a domain with uri

Tags: redirect, nginx, uri, subdomain, response

I have this scenario. I want to redirect in nginx all subdomains in this format.

(profile_name).mydomain.com
mydomain.com/profile/(profile_name)

How can I do this in nginx?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression `server` block.

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<name>.+)\.example\.com$;
    return 301 http://example.com/profile/$name$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.